# Akka avoiding wrapping future when responding to non-Actor code

Tags: scala, akka, future

I'm making a small caching actor with Akka 2 and to make the actor not block I perform all calculations inside futures. However a problem is that this actor also need to interact with with code that is not itself in an actor, so that I need to use the "ask" pattern to get a value.

My question is, how do I avoid wrapping the Future of my calculation inside another Future when using the ask pattern?

For example

```
val f = myCache ? GetOrCalc("myKey", myCalculation) // this will be a Future[Future[...]] but I would like a Future[...]

// meanwhile, inside the actor
def receive = {
    case GetOrCalc(key, calculation) =>
        if (keyNotExists) sender ! Future { calculation() } // calculation() is long-running
        else sender ! cacheMap(key)
}
```

Ideally I could use the Future.pipeTo function but I'm afraid this doesn't get counted as a "response" for non-actor code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
val f = myCache ? GetOrCalc("myKey", myCalculation)

def receive = {
    case GetOrCalc(key, calculation) =>
        if (keyNotExists) Future { calculation() } pipeTo sender
        else sender ! cacheMap(key)
}
```

Send-And-Receive-Future">http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/scala/actors.html#Ask_Send-And-Receive-Future

Comment: Strangely, this is exactly what I had in my original pseudocode and didn't even test it because I assumed that the pipeTo wasn't going to work as a "response". That's what I get for not testing and just assuming! Although truth be told this behaviour is not in the docs as I mentioned above. Thanks a lot Viktor!

Comment: I'm wondering how "pipeTo sender" is safely accessing sender.  I understand why you can't access sender from within the Future, but how come pipeTo sender doesn't have the same issue.Is it because pipeTo evaluates sender in the context of the actor before the Future completes?

Comment: It doesn't close over the sender "then", it closes over the value of the sender "now". Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, I think so.  From looking at the source for pipeTo, I can see that it call the pipeTo immediately on the implicitly created PipeableFuture object, which will evaluate sender immediately, but delays execution of the actual actor send by using the onComplete callback.  As always, thanks for your help in figuring this out, Rob

Comment: One further comment, presumably, on the code sample below, sender is not being safely accessed.  Or have I not yet grasped how these Future things work? :-)

Answer (score 3):

Add onComplete to the calculation future.

```
def receive = {
    case GetOrCalc(key, calculation) =>
        if (keyNotExists) // calculation() is long-running
            Future { calculation() } onComplete {
                case Right(result) => result match {
                        case Some(value) => sender ! value
                        case None => sender ! Status.Failure(new Exception("Cannot find the value"))
                    }
                case Left(ex) =>
                    sender ! Status.Failure(ex)

            }
        else sender ! cacheMap(key)
}
```

And there is an article about using Akka to build a cache system. http://letitcrash.com/post/30509298968/case-study-an-auto-updating-cache-using-actors

Comment: But doesn't this send twice? Once a Future[Future[...]] (sender ! Future { ... }) and another time a Future[...] (sender ! value)? Does it work for non-actor calling code? How do you use the CalcResult message?

Comment: updated the code. Actually this solution is coming from the article (http://letitcrash.com/post/30509298968/case-study-an-auto-updating-cache-using-actors) and I don't have the time to verify it for now. Hope this is a helpful clue for you.

Comment: Hehe, thanks! I was reading that source a couple of hours ago actually because it talks about Akka and caching. I guess I hadn't read it thoroughly enough, it seems to do things more or less the way I wanted to do them after closer inspection. If it works as expected I'll elect your answer as the right one

Comment: That is correct.  Sending a value to the asker will complete the future.  And sending Status.Failure will send an exception (see http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/scala/futures.html)

Comment: @sourcedelica nice, I tried looking for that in the askpatterns source on github but couldn't find it (I found a special ActorRef). So is it correct to assume that it is an Actor that completes a Future with whatever it receives first and then dies? In that case it's pretty nifty and I should be able to use pipeTo. Shame that this isn't documented (couldn't find it on the Futures page nor on the Actors page).

Comment: Noooo... don't close over "sender" and expose that to other threads, that's exactly what pipeTo is aimed to prevent: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/general/jmm.html#Actors_and_shared_mutable_state

Comment: Except for that - don't close over the sender :)

Comment: It was pretty difficult to decide who should get the "right answer" here as both you guys helped me out, shame you can't approve 2 answers!

Comment: The pipeTo thing is super clean and definitely recommended when you can use it.  The code above can't use pipeTo because it checks the value of the future before it sends the result back to the caller.  (Correct me if I am wrong Victor).  That is it returns a value or an exception back to the asker, versus sending a Some/None.